# A method uses an array and returns an array, but I am using an array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So, this is my dilemma. I have a class called:

```
public petShop()
```

and I used an `ArrayList` to collect all the strings (names of pets).

```
ArrayList<String> petNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, when using a different signature with an array in, the return type gives an error.

Any help?

```
public String[] getPetNames() {
return petNames;
```

Comment: Are there a fixed amount of names that you can accept in the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get back an array from your ArrayList simply, using `toArray`.

```
public String [] getPetNameAsStringArray() {
    return petNames.toArray(new String[petNames.size()]);
}
```